# With an Oracle APEX form, is it possible to have other fields grey out based on other picks from a drop down menu?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a "Form" typed menu... in Oracle Application Express. In the menu, you pick whether you are raising a Problem or a Change. If you raise a Change, I want the estimated date of resolution field to be greyed out, because it's not relevant and might confuse users. Does anyone have any advice on how I may best achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Actions are what you need. You can define a dynamic action to occur on change of an item, which can show/hide other components.

[image]

The client-side condition decides true vs false.

See 'Creating an enable/disable declarative dynamic action in this [OBE](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r51/dynamic_actions/dynamic_actions.html).

You could also check out other dynamic action examples with an application Juergen created [here](http://dynamic-actions.com/)

Or even use them to [invoke PL/SQL](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/10/apex-101-dynamic-actions.html)

Comment: You made my Day. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dynamic actions are awesome http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/10/otn-appreciation-day-apex-dynamic-actions-jquery-selector.html ;p